# How could generate a numerical value on Time?

Tags: r

I have time data for mixed linear analysis.
I hope to use R to center on time to get a numerical value.

Below is an example:

```
TIME = 0 at Wave 1 (0 month, September 2006), 
TIME = 0.67 at Wave 2 (8 months, May 2007), 
TIME = 1 at Wave 3 (12 months, September 2007), 
TIME = 1.67 at Wave 4 (20 months, May 2008), 
TIME = 2 at Wave 5 (24 months, September 2008), 
TIME = 2.67 at Wave 6 (32 months, May 2009).
```

Expected format:

```
Time = ？ Wave 1 is April 2020
Time = ？ Wave 2 is July 2020
Time = ？ Wave 3 is Jan 2021
Time = ？ Wave 4 is April 2021
```

I hope to calculate the numerical value **Time**.

How could I use R to generate a **Time** Value like the example shows?

Comment: @ Wave 1(0 month, September 2006) is an example:)

Comment: Exactly what is the input and what is the output and what are the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm unfamiliar with this approach, but it doesn't look like you are "centering." It looks like you are calculating **durations**. Specifically, each of the values in the example that you give are just the time (in years) since wave 1 (i.e., May 2009 is 2.67 years from Sep 2006). There's nothing wrong with this, I just want to make sure we are working on the same problem.

Assuming you are just looking for the amount of time between two dates, you have two options.

### Option 1: Lubridate

The `lubridate` package is generally the easiest way to work with dates. If you don't use it yet, I think you'll really appreciate how easy it makes handling dates and times in R (but it does need to be installed with "`install.packages('lubridate')`".

```
library(lubridate)

wave_dates <- c('April 1, 2020', 'July 1, 2020', 'Jan 1, 2021', 'April 1, 2021')
wave_dates <- mdy(wave_dates) # lubridate converts from string to date objects


# get times in years  
(wave_dates - min(wave_dates))/dyears(1)

# > [1] 0.0000000 0.2491444 0.7529090 0.9993155
```

### Option 2: Base R

If you want to use base R, you'll need to make sure your dates are converted into a format R can understand with `strptime()`. Make sure to consult `?strptime()`'s documentation for all of the different formatting instructions you can give it (there are a lot). In this case, we need...

```
wave_dates <- c('April 1, 2020', 'July 1, 2020', 'January 1, 2021', 'April 1, 2021')
wave_dates <- strptime(wave_dates, '%B %d, %Y') # base R converts from string to date objects


difftime(wave_dates, min(wave_dates), units = 'days') / 365
#> [1] 0.0000000 0.2493151 0.7535388 1.0000000
```

Note that when using `difftime()` we need to divide our answer by 365 because it doesn't have a `units = 'years'` option. This is because some years (leap years) are a different length than others and base R is generally not designed to handle that. In contrast, `lubridate` can.